# Make the Accordion works on click event of a button

Tags: jquery

I have an [Accordion](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/accordion/) in my page

At the end of each header, I have a button, I want that the accordion open her content just when the user click on the button and not on the header.

My idea is identify from where comes the click, I don't if this is the best approach.

```
// My Button at the end of the Header
$("#divAtender").click(function (data) {
    if ($("#content1").is(":visible") == true) {
        $("#accordion").accordion({ active: false });
    }
    else {
        $("#accordion").accordion({ active: 0 });
    }            
});

//Change event of my Accordion    
$("#accordion").on("accordionchange", function (event, ui) {            
       // How can I discover that my button was triggered or not
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="accordion">
   <h3 class="segundoPost" style="color: #ffffff !important;">
      New Contract
          <div id="divAtender" style="float: right; margin-right: 10px;">
               Atend
          </div>
   </h3>
   <div id="content1" style="display: none;">
         @* anything here *@
   </div>
</div>
```

When I click on the header (`<h3>`) the accordion shows my `<div id='content1'>` and this should happens just when click on my `<div id='divAtender'>`

Comment: Why can you not use the button as selector?

Comment: Do you have a sample ?

Comment: I think he's suggesting you change your $("#divAtender") selector to whatever your button is.

Comment: divAtender is a <div> that I use as a button with some CSS.

Comment: You can test whether the button is actually firing by putting a console.log('Button Clicked') in the first function and then put console.log('Event Fired) in the second one. Then you can see which one is actually being called. Or you can use breakpoints if you know how.

Comment: So I guess right now the accordion opens when you click on the header and the button? But you want it to only activate on the button?

Comment: @Lucas_Santos I think the answer is as close to it as it gets because the doc says you can define the 'header' element but it needs to be a sibling of the content. Tanatos's answer basically unbinds the default accordion header and binds click to an element of your choice which fits your need here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following (you will need to adapt it to your needs) : http://jsfiddle.net/qYguY/2/

```
$("#accordion").accordion();
$("#accordion .ui-accordion-header").unbind('click');
$(".accordion_options").click(function() {
    var current = parseInt($(this).attr("rel"));
    if(typeof current !== "undefined")
        $("#accordion").accordion({ active: current });
});
```

Comment: Very good, I think I should put the css class in my HTML tag. So this is generate by the plugin, good to know. Thanks!